# Log4j2 SMTP-Appender "Must issue a STARTTLS command first"

Tags: java, email, smtp, log4j2, smtpappender

I am trying to send log entries with severity "error" via email in java. 
In my log4j2.xml file I have the following SMTP appender:

```
<SMTP>
name="Mail"
subject="Error Log"
to="receiver@domain.com"
from="sender@domain.com"
smtpHost="SMTP-Host"
smtpPort="587"
smtpPassword="[password]" 
smtpUsername="email@domain.com"
smtpDebug="true"
ignoreExceptions="false"
bufferSize="4"
smtpProtocol="smtp">
</SMTP>
```

But when I run my programm (which consists of a main logging a string) the following error occurs:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7
13:13:44.469 [main] ERROR Main - Test Error
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "SMTP-Host", port 587, isSSL false
220 SMTP-Host ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "SMTP-Host", port: 587

EHLO MAXPC
250-SMTP-Host
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 52428800
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "52428800"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ETRN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<sender@domain.com>
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
DEBUG SMTP: got response code 530, with response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

RSET
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending, THROW: 
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1609)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1117)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.sendMultipartMessage(SmtpManager.java:257)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.sendEvents(SmtpManager.java:172)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SmtpAppender.append(SmtpAppender.java:181)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:464)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:448)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:431)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:406)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2170)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2108)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2007)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1866)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.error(Log4jLogger.java:299)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
QUIT
221 2.0.0 Bye
2019-03-03 13:13:49,204 main ERROR SmtpManager SMTP:848b9401aab8a35f62b00f0dbdf21fd4 Caught exception while sending e-mail notification.: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
 com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1609)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1117)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.sendMultipartMessage(SmtpManager.java:257)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.sendEvents(SmtpManager.java:172)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SmtpAppender.append(SmtpAppender.java:181)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:464)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:448)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:431)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:406)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2170)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2108)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2007)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1866)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.error(Log4jLogger.java:299)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)

2019-03-03 13:13:49,206 main ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender Mail org.apache.logging.log4j.LoggingException: Error occurred while sending email
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.sendEvents(SmtpManager.java:175)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SmtpAppender.append(SmtpAppender.java:181)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:464)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:448)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:431)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:406)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2170)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2108)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2007)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1866)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.error(Log4jLogger.java:299)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1609)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1117)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.sendMultipartMessage(SmtpManager.java:257)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.sendEvents(SmtpManager.java:172)
    ... 18 more

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: An exception occurred processing Appender Mail
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.DefaultErrorHandler.error(DefaultErrorHandler.java:75)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.handleAppenderError(AppenderControl.java:165)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:158)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:464)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:448)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:431)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:406)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2170)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2108)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2007)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1866)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.error(Log4jLogger.java:299)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
Caused by: org.apache.logging.log4j.LoggingException: Error occurred while sending email
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.sendEvents(SmtpManager.java:175)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SmtpAppender.append(SmtpAppender.java:181)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2108)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1609)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1117)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.sendMultipartMessage(SmtpManager.java:257)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.SmtpManager.sendEvents(SmtpManager.java:172)
    ... 18 more
```

As far as I understand the programm can establish a connection to the server but then `Must issue a STARTTLS command first` this happens. Can someone explain to me what that means and how to fix it?

When I searched for the error I got a few posts with similar problems but not with log4j2 but with java.mail and they didn't helped me.

I tried using `smtpPort="465"` and `smtpProtocol="smtps"` but in both cases the connection got refused.

I have no more new ideas and am grateful for everyone who helps me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue and it looks like log4j2 is not capable of handling STARTTLS. Fortunately log4j uses the system properties when creating the mail session. So my fix is using

*smtpProtocol="smtp"*

for the SMTP appender and setting the system property

*mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true*

on the command line to activate STARTTLS for the mail session. You could alternatively use

*System.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true")*

in your application code.